# Programmatically display images from JSON into TableRow

Tags: android, tablerow

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to display a list of images inside a `TableRow` which is inside a `HorizontalScrollView` and I'm a little bit lost because at the moment I have all the entries from a JSON file (with the full URL path from my website where the images are stores) but I don't know how to display my images using `ImageView` inside the `TableRow`.

**This is my code:**

```
public void loadMarcas(final MarcaAdapter adapter) {

// List View
final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listv);

// Attach the adapter to a ListView
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());

            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray(keyJSON);

            // Create blog items
            for(int i = 0; i<jsonMainNode.length();i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = jsonChildNode.getString("id");
                String name = jsonChildNode.getString("name");
                String image = jsonChildNode.getString("image");

                Marca newMarca = new Marca(id, name, image);
                adapter.add(newMarca);
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e) {
            // Display error
            Log.d("Error", e.toString());
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // Display error
        Log.d("Error", error.toString());
    }
});

// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
}
```

And this is my XML:

```
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/opcion4"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:onClick="onClickListadoProductos"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:minHeight="95dp">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listv"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">
            </ListView>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Comment: It seems that you don't wire the code from the JSONRequest with the layout. Where is your adapter?

Comment: I think your question is too broad. Is your problem related to the loading of images? or is it related to creating an adapter? or is it related to the layout itself?

Comment: Hi @thyagostall, that's where I'm lost. So I need and adapter to put the images into the TableRow? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Merlevede, it's related to the adapter because I wasn't sure that I need to create one to put the images there.

Comment: @JordiGámez, In this case I guess that a RecyclerView is more appropriated. Check out how to do it: https://www.raywenderlich.com/126528/android-recyclerview-tutorial

Comment: Thanks @thyagostall I'm going to check the tutorial!

Comment: I have update the first post with the latest code I made and I'm almost there. The problem now is that I can't scroll my ScrollView. It may be because it's nested inside another ScrollView? Thanks in advance.